# react native - Creating header above FlatList which scrolls up when scroll drag hits it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onscroll, react-native-flatlist

The effect I'm looking for is a bit hard to describe, but I'm basically trying to implement a header above a scrollView which allows you to scroll normally when touching inside the scrollView, but then when you drag up out of the scrollView onto the header, it moves the header up.

This effect is used with the iPhone keyboard as a footer for messages for example, where you can scroll through messages normally and the keyboard will stay. However, if you scroll down into the keyboard, it drags the keyboard down.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboarddismissmode 'interactive' is the effect I'm trying to achieve, but instead of for a keyboard I'm looking to do it for some custom header component which is above my scrollView.

I figure I could match the scroll to the components Y translate Y, however I only want to do this depending on where my touch is. Sadly, the onScroll event doesn't seem to contain any information on the touch location, so I can't tell where the user is dragging. Any help or ideas for other ways to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use  `https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e` .  `https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-collapsible-navbar-e51a049b560a`

Comment: Sadly neither of those give the effect I'm after, I currently have something like that implemented, but it's not what I want. I want to be able to scroll without moving the header, but when you drag it into the header it moves it up. The same effect as iOS keyboard interactions.

Comment: @PhilipVasseur did you manage to implement this? I want the exact same behavior but can't seem to find anything to help...